# gray highlighting is gone

Tags: xorg, colors, display

Gray text highlighting no longer works on my Debian/stretch system. Neither in Emacs for indicating the selected region, nor here in the browser editor for text `within backticks`.

Which system level could be responsible for this problem?

How should I proceed to debug?

Comment: What happen if you add `(set-face-background 'region "midnightblue")` into your `~/.emacs`?

Comment: The selected region is highlighted in a background color that very much looks like midnightblue.

Comment: With "gray" instead of "midnightblue" it works as well. So it seems the problem is that different applications (Emacs, Iceweasel) use a system default for selection highlighting color, and that this default has been accidentally set to white or transparent.

Comment: It seems you just have not-configured system. If it happened during last system update it is possible that some files from /etc directory has been acidentally(?) removed. Hard to tell. You need to set colors for those applications separately.

Comment: www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Standard-Faces.html says about the "region" face: "When Emacs is built with GTK support, its colors are taken from the current GTK theme." Quite possible that the problem appeared after I installed or deinstalled something GTK related. I'm not running gnome, but xfce4. What exactly is the relation between emacs and GTK, and how can I set a reasonable default highlighting color without installing GTK?

Comment: After installing the package gtk3-engines-xfce, the region highlighting in Emacs is back. However, it still doesn't work in the browser.